# How can I show my current location in maps in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, geolocation

I watched a few lessons on Youtube and now tried to get hands-on experience. I am pursuing a little project which involves a tabbed app where I tried on the first page to create a map with a button showing the current location. Pretty basic actually. But somehow it just doesn’t work and I don’t know what’s the issue. Someone from CodewithChris told me this “I would suggest breaking up your app into smaller components and making sure each one works before going on to the next. Try outputting your location first before plotting it on a map etc so you can localize bugs easier.” I just don’t understand what she means by smaller components. I really appreciate all the help I can get. Below is the code as good as possible. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
import UIKit

import MapKit

import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textFieldForAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var getDirectionsButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

    var locationManger = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManger.delegate = self
        locationManger.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManger.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManger.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManger.startUpdatingLocation()

        map.delegate = self

    }

    @IBAction func getDirectionsTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        getAddress()
    }


    func getAddress() {
        let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(textFieldForAddress.text!) { (placemarks, error) in
            guard let placemarks = placemarks, let location = placemarks.first?.location
                else {
                    print("No Location Found")
                    return
            }
            print(location)
            self.mapThis(destinationCord: location.coordinate)

        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print(locations)
    }

    func mapThis(destinationCord : CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        let souceCordinate = (locationManger.location?.coordinate)!

        let soucePlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: souceCordinate)
        let destPlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCord)

        let sourceItem = MKMapItem(placemark: soucePlaceMark)
        let destItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destPlaceMark)

        let destinationRequest = MKDirections.Request()
        destinationRequest.source = sourceItem
        destinationRequest.destination = destItem
        destinationRequest.transportType = .automobile
        destinationRequest.requestsAlternateRoutes = true

        let directions = MKDirections(request: destinationRequest)
        directions.calculate { (response, error) in
            guard let response = response else {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Something is wrong :(")
                }
                return
            }

          let route = response.routes[0]
          self.map.addOverlay(route.polyline)
          self.map.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect, animated: true)

        }


    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let render = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay as! MKPolyline)
        render.strokeColor = .blue
        return render
    }


}
```

Comment: All you need to do is request `whenInUseAuthorization` from `CLLocationManager` and set `showsUserLocation` to `true` on your mapView.

Comment: Hi thanks first of all for the answer unfortunately I am so uneducated in coding yet that i dont know where to insert your suggestions anyhow you could help me with that?

Comment: I can add an answer shortly, but you literally only need those two lines. You can remove most of the code that you have. You already have then when in use authorisation request. Keep that. Add `map.showsUserLocation=true` under it.  Done.  You can set shows user location on your map in the storyboard and then you don't even need that line of code.

Comment: I did exactly what you said except of deleting everything, but it still doesn't work even chain gin it in the storyboard. Sorry to bother you so much.

Comment: What didn't work?  Are you running on a simulator or a real device?  If you are on the simulator did you use the menu to simulate a location? Did you scroll the map to show your  location?  If you want the map to scroll automatically you have to set a user tracking mode or perform the scroll in code.

Comment: I use a simulator. I want to have a user tracking mode and a blue pin showing my location, I totally forgot to mention that.

Comment: Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the user location and have the map track it, you need to set two properties on the map view - `showsUserLocation` and `userTrackingMode`.  In order for the map to have access to the user location you must receive `whenInUse` authorisation from the user, using `CLocationManager`.

```
import MapKit

import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textFieldForAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var getDirectionsButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

    var locationManger = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManger.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        map.userTrackingMode = .follow

    }
```

If you are running on the simulator then you need to simulate a location using the *Debug* menu in the simulator.

Comment: I inserted the code from above and even to Debug in simulator but somehow I don't get the authorisation message although I've inserted the privacy thing in info.plst

Comment: Have you ever received the authorisation request?  That is a one-time-only thing.  Once you have responded to that request you will never get prompted again.  You will get information in the console if the info.plist usage string isn't present.

Comment: No never that's the weirdest thing!

Comment: Check you app settings in the "Settings app" - What does it show for location?  Do you get any messages in the console regarding location permission?

Comment: I have created a bare-bones project that implements user tracking - https://github.com/paulw11/MapTrackingDemo

Comment: 2020-01-25 23:03:17.712413+0200 MAP_1[22212:557746] [Storyboard] Unknown class _TtC5MAP_119FirstViewController in Interface Builder file.
2020-01-25 23:03:17.899055+0200 MAP_1[22212:557746] Metal API Validation Enabled

Comment: 2020-01-25 23:03:18.061152+0200 MAP MobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:1647: Could not retrieve region info
2020-01-25 23:23:41.506017+0200 MAP_1[22212:557746] Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1 (0x1), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.
2020-01-25 23:24:31.537182+0200 MAP_1[22212:557746] Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 6 (0x6), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9

Comment: Ok, so that means that the custom class of your scene is set to "FirstViewController", but your class name is "ViewController" from your source, so it can't find your code.  It will be using a default `UIViewController` that doesn't do anything.

Comment: I just changed it to FirstViewController but now I get the message Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: at map.ShowUserLocation = true

Comment: That means you haven't connected the map view in your storyboard to your `map` outlet. Use the connections inspector in the storyboard and drag from the "new referencing outlet" to your view controller and select "map" from the pop up

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it by clicking on the tick.

Comment: I dont know why but I tried it again today and today I can't connect my storyboard to my ViewController not with the drag and drop and not manually. Im frustrated

Comment: Check the custom class of your scene. It sounds like you have the wrong view controller class

Comment: Still no success. I am using the tabbed app which means it comes with 3 windows in the storyboard. I am trying to set up a fourth one wich is a third option down at the tab. The problem now I'm having is that I also created a new ViewController but can't connect it to the new window in the storyboard.

Comment: You probably need to ask a new question at this point, but you need to link the new scene to the tab bar controller by ctrl dragging from the tab bar to the new scene

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this information is surprising hard to find (just getting your own location!) — even after watching tutorials I had a hard time. But basically what you're missing is `mapView.showsUserLocation = true`

Here's the full code, if you need it...

```
 import UIKit
 import CoreLocation
 import MapKit

  class RadiusMapLocationViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.97823607957177, -118.43823725357653)

var locationManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

// Authorize use of location
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
  mapView.showsUserLocation = (status == .authorizedAlways)
}

// Entering region
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
         showAlert(withTitle: "You've entered \(region.identifier)", message: "Happy hopping!")
}

// Exiting region
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
       showAlert(withTitle: "You've exited \(region.identifier)", message: "")
}

// Creating region and notifying when exit / enter
func region(with geotification: Geotification) -> CLCircularRegion {
  let region = CLCircularRegion(center: geotification.coordinate,
    radius: geotification.radius,
    identifier: geotification.identifier)
  region.notifyOnEntry = (geotification.eventType == .onEntry)
  region.notifyOnExit = !region.notifyOnEntry
  return region
}

// Monitoring region, if not "error"
   func startMonitoring(geotification: Geotification) {
     if !CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLCircularRegion.self) {
       showAlert(withTitle:"Error", message: "Geofencing is not supported on this device!")
       return
     }
}

   func stopMonitoring(geotification: Geotification) {
     for region in locationManager.monitoredRegions {
       guard let circularRegion = region as? CLCircularRegion,
         circularRegion.identifier == geotification.identifier else { continue }
       locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: circularRegion)
     }
   }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    // Region of coordinate
    mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 800, longitudinalMeters: 800)

    mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000)

    let title = "Marina Bar Hop"
    let restaurantAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    restaurantAnnotation.coordinate = coordinate
    restaurantAnnotation.title = title
    mapView.addAnnotation(restaurantAnnotation)

    let regionRadius = 300.0
    let circle = MKCircle(center: coordinate, radius: regionRadius)
    mapView.addOverlay(circle)

    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self as? CLLocationManagerDelegate

    //Zoom to user location
    if let userLocation = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
        let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation, latitudinalMeters: 200, longitudinalMeters: 200)
        mapView.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: false)
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
    circleRenderer.lineWidth = 1.0
    return circleRenderer
    }
}
```

I have a few additional features on here if you need them. And it sounds like maybe you want to add a pin on the user's current location? It's included in this code too. I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Oh also be sure you're using your iPhone instead of a simulator with this. In my experience, only the iPhone will show your location. And by "smaller components", I believe it's in reference where the issues/bugs might pop up. For example, think "where would I add breakpoints in this code?" By having different functions separated, it lets you add better breakpoints and catch errors (without everything being jumbled together).

Comment: thank you very much but when I tried inserting your code into Xcode it shows at leat 10 wrong values? can you help me with that ? and yes I want a pin on the user current location. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a previous version of my code, so maybe I have some old stuff in there that is giving you an error? Can you tell me a few of the issues? Also, take a look at this question I asked: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903284/how-to-add-circle-around-map-pin-in-swift/59912595#59912595

It has more details on how to create a pin / geofence ^ and also links to my GitHub with a ton of code you can use.

Comment: I'm currently updating "RadiusLocationViewController", so give me an hour and it should be everything you need.

Comment: - Use of undeclared type 'Geotification'

Comment: Those kind of errors and a lot more. I would send a screenshot but its not possible. I dont know how to thank you already for your help and patience with me!

Comment: Okay I've just updated the code so this should work for you now: 

https://github.com/kcapretta/RadiusSocialNetworkingApp/blob/master/RadiusMap/RadiusLocationViewController

However, I'm still figuring out how to add a circle around the pin. I believe I have code conflicting with each other. Hope this helps!

Comment: I just tried it but it still shows me errors at the show alert line and geotifidcation. Thanks nevertheless

Comment: Okay sorry that's my bad. I just realized I have Swift Files looped into this View Controller. Here's the coordinating files that you should be able to cut & paste into new files / VCs: https://github.com/kcapretta/RadiusSocialNetworkingApp/tree/master/RadiusMap